# Converting Word document to TIFF?

Tags: linux, microsoft-word, conversion, centos, tiff

I have a CentOS 5.6 box and was wondering if there are any tools for Linux that can convert a Microsoft Word document to a TIFF file?

Comment: You'd need something that can read/render the word file. OpenOffice is a candidate, though I have no idea how scriptable it is by external apps.

Answer (score 1):

don't think currently CUPS has a printer driver for TIFF -- however, you can print to PDF : http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=slackware:cups

Comment: To piggy-back, yes: print to PDF, and then use ImageMagick to convert to tif. See [HERE](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and [HERE](http://www.ehow.com/how_5148734_convert-pdf-tiff-using-imagemagick.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an online service to convert the doc file to PNG, then to TIFF.  One such service is http://www.zamzar.com/